# How to do update with join

Tags: mysql, sql, database

just think I have a table1 like shown below

```
table1

id  product
2   chocolate
1   chocolate
2   pepsi
3   fanta
2   pepsi
4   chocolate
5   chips
3   pizza
1   coke
2   chips
6   burger
7   sprite
0   pepsi
```

and want to arrange the above table in the manner shown below using only mysql

```
table2

id  product
0   pepsi
1   chocolate, coke
2   chocolate,fanta,chips
3   fanta,pizza
4   chocolate
5   chips
6   burger
7   sprite
```

the above thing can be done by using

```
select id, group_concat(distinct product) as products 
from table1 
group by id 
order by id
```

and after that i want the product column from table2 to be updated in another table which is named table3, which is shown below, here i want to update the products column from table2 as things column in table3 and the number in table3 = id from table2

```
table3

number  name      things
0       hi        null
1       hello     null
2       hehe      null
3       wow       null
4       hi        null
5       hi        null
6       hi        null
7       hi        null
```

and i want the final output to be shown as in table2

```
table3

number  name    things
0       hi      pepsi
1       hello   chocolate, coke
2       hehe    chocolate,fanta,chips
3       wow     fanta,pizza
4       hi      chocolate
5       hi      chips
6       hi      burger
7       hi      sprite
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `update from select` syntax. [**Check here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) for more info

```
UPDATE table3
       JOIN (SELECT id,
                    Group_concat(DISTINCT product) AS products
             FROM   table1
             GROUP  BY id) b
         ON table3.number = b.id
SET    table3.things = b.products
```

Comment: but i did try that..but gave me an error..!!still i'll try it again..would have missed something i guess..thank you anyway..

Comment: @CheranPrakash In table3 you have a column `number`, not`id`so change`ON table3.id = b.id`to`ON table3.number = b.id` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have a nice normalized data structure and you want to start putting in comma-separated lists.  That is a bad idea.  Doable, but probably a bad idea.

You would use an `update` with a `join`:

```
update table3 t3 join
       (select id, group_concat(distinct product) as products
        from table1
        group by id
       ) tt
       on t3.number = tt.id
    set t3.things = tt.products;
```